# Pycharm will not properly layout new suggestions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, pycharm

I recently downloaded a updated version of Pycharm and Python 2 and 3 on my new MacBook. I keep getting a issue when I type a line of code underneath a for loop it will not display more suggestions.

For example when I type `links_loc = link.` the only suggestion that I receive is main, not and par but I want to put `links_loc = links.text`. This will work properly once I run the code but sometime I do not know what I want to put. Since I am using BeautifulSoup I might want to put `links_loc = links.find_all("image:image")` but it does not work properly.

Everything worked properly on my older MacBook. Just can not figure the problem.

Comment: Did you install request and BS4?

Comment: Have you set Project Interpreter in PyCharm settings?

Comment: yes I install both requests and bs4 using pip. @AndMar

Comment: @RomanMindlin I did set a project interpreter in pycharm still not working.